# Logging settings overriden

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, azureportal

I have settings like this:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  }
```

And in Azure App Service Logs I have set Information level:

[image]

And now it logs Information level for `Microsoft` and `System` logs even they are set at `Warning` level in `appsettings`.

Anyone knows how I can fix this?

Comment: Set application logging level to `Warning`?

Comment: I cannot do that, I want my app logs to be information, but Microsoft and System logs to be Warning. Like it is in console on localhost. On Azure it seems I cannot differentiate them. Its one log level for everything.

Answer (score 0):

As @Peter Bons, suggested we can check according to our specified requirement (Like;warning,Information,Verbose,Errors) logs by selecting them from **App service logs > Level(Warning)> Save** .

[image]

For more information please refer this [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/492274/filter-logging-for-azure-application-insights.html) & [Blog](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-configure-azure-web-app-logging-with-net-5-786918eb2ff3)